# If statement not working with AND

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

I'm trying to make sure that my twitter feed is served a certain way, cached or new.  I'm using the code below to try to make sure if the cached file is old and additionally if at the same time I still have enough attempts left in my twitter rate limit.  Problem is that the statement isn't seeming to work right, yet I can't figure out why.  I've tried with both operators '&&' and 'AND', and neither work.  Any idea?

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/account/rate_limit_status.json", true);
$decode = json_decode($json, true);
$twitter_rate_remaining = $decode['remaining_hits'];

if(((time()-filectime($file)) > 1800) && ($twitter_rate_remaining > 5)) { //do something }
```

Comment: SUGGESTION: echo the values of "time()-filectime($file)" and "$twitter_rate_remaining".  You might be surprised :)

Answer (score 0):

Note: we do not know what $file is from your question - where does it come from? What OS and filesystem are you using?

However, I suspect you want to be using filemtime to check for updates to a cached file.

It has nothing to do with && or AND, but what the boolean values of your two conditions are - that's what boolean logic means. If either of the values are false, then the whole test will be false.

Do some debugging:

```
var_dump(time());
var_dump(filectime($file));
var_dump(time() - filectime($file));

var_dump(time()-filectime($file)) > 1800); // output boolean true or false

var_dump($twitter_rate_remaining);

var_dump($twitter_rate_remaining > 5); // output boolean true or false;

var_dump((time()-filectime($file)) > 1800) && ($twitter_rate_remaining > 5)); // output boolean true or false
```

That way, you can see which of the conditions are false.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  I did not have this included in my function.  I had it outside.  Doh!

$json = file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/account/rate_limit_status.json", true);
$decode = json_decode($json, true);
$twitter_rate_remaining = $decode['remaining_hits'];

So I wasn't able to get the $twitter_rate_remaining value until I moved it into it.